# How to pass a mutli-dimensional array when testing a POST call in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, testing

I'm testing a POST method in my project and it calls for a multidimensional array as a parameter. How do I pass this through Laravel's `post()` method? I'm also trying the `postJson()` method. The multi-array I'm testing is filters["excludes"]:

```
public function testExcludeFilter()
    {
        $json = '
        {
            "northLatitude":45.123456,
            "southLatitude":45.123456,
            "eastLongitude":9.1234567,
            "westLongitude":9.1234567,
            "filters": {
                "excludes": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        }
        ';

        $response = $this->postJson('api/v1/getHotels', $json)
            ->dontSeeJson([
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Hotel-1',
                'latitude' => 45.123456,
                'longitude' => 9.1234567
                ]);

        $response->assertResponseStatus(200);
    }
```

Error received:

`ErrorException: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase::postJson() must be of the type array, string given`

I also tried to pass my data as an array, but it did not pay attention to the exclude filter:

```
postJson('api/v1/getHotels', ['northLatitude' => '45.123456', 'southLatitude' => '45.123456', 'westLongitude' => '9.1234567', 'eastLongitude' => '9.1234567', 'filters["excludes"]' => [1]]
```

Comment: `$response = $this->postJson('api/v1/getHotels', json_decode($json, true))` This will convert json to array

Comment: thanks this is the answer

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Please could you put your comment in an answer so that the question can be marked as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$response = $this->postJson('api/v1/getHotels', json_decode($json, true))
            ->dontSeeJson([
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Hotel-1',
                'latitude' => 45.123456,
                'longitude' => 9.1234567
                ]);
```

Json_decode($json, true) will convert your json data to array.